# Whenever i try to launch my app I'm getting WebDriverException and in command prompt it says POST //session 404 in the debug level

Tags: automation, appium-android, automation-testing, mobile-app-testing

WebDriverException: Message: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource

I've given host address, platform name, device name, activity and all the required variables to launch an app

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

here's one of the solution using which I'd sorted out my error.
Run your appium instance by providing base path in cmd as "appium --base-path /wd/hub"
this is applicable only if you've set your localhost path as "http://localhost:4723/wd/hub" to launch your app.

Thanks!